# Shortcode in pages or tempate files for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, shortcode

I am using WordPress to develop a coupon site. Merchant `pages` are somewhat similar to [this](http://www.promotionalcodes.org.uk/accountz/). I am using shortcodes in these `pages` for Facebook Like, Google +1, Customer Review, Codes from similar stores etc. The thing I want to ask is: is this a good way of doing all that? I am comparing this particularly with theme based solution i.e. developing templates files for custom (non-hierarchical) post type.

Which one would be more fast and elegant? Any other suggestion is welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lucas Wynne linked some good plugins for such functionalities (I have used Addthis multiple times), however if you're looking for a plugin-free solution, i'd more likely filter the content in my functions.php file instead of using a shortcode :

some pseudo-code

```
 function add_content( $content ){
     $content .= "<a href=\"facebook\">FACEBOOK</a>";
     return $content;
}
```

For more info on the content filter : http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: thanks for your answer. My question is more towards the  design than incorporating sharing solutions. That's why I mentioned other shortcodes as well. Basically, I want to add these only to pages that represent individual merchants but not on pages that show list of merchants

Comment: If your "Merchants" is a custom post type, i'd go with template files. You say "individual merchants", so the appropriate template file would be single-merchants.php if your CPT is called "merchants". Adding your your code / echoing shortcodes in that template file would be adding it for all individual merchants, and quicker than writing a shortcode in each post.

Comment: Useful diagram : http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Answer (score 0):

Forget shortcodes for this.

Use one of these services:

Addthis: http://www.addthis.com/

Sharethis: http://sharethis.com/

They're free and will give you better insights.